# Output panorama shows color shift wrt input image [Hugin]

Tags: color, panorama, hugin

I'm using Hugin to create a panorama of a countryside vista. I have three input images to create the panorama. The three images were shot in RAW, same camera settings for all three images, and processed using the same parameters in Rawtherapee. For info, all three images contain an embedded colour profile, RTv4_sRGB.

The problem that I have is that in the output panorama image
[image]
there is a strong colour shift visible on right hand side part that is not visible in the input image corresponding to that part, see the below side by side comparison and look especially at the colour of the hill. There seems to equally be a slight change in exposure as well.
[image]

When I created the panorama in Hugin the only option I could select for the output was the 'Exposure corrected, low dynamic range' one.

Did any of you encounter such a problem before? Or, does anyone have an idea as to why this colour shift is happening? Any help will be much appreciated.

All the best.

Comment: Colour exposure shifts do happen with Hugin, can you add some information on your workflow? What file type and colour depth are you importing? How are you using Hugin? eg. I tend to import 16 bit tiffs, add control points, correct for exposure, and align with the most basic mode. I then edit control points and gradually go through the alignment types whilst updating the field of view, canvas size and crop till I get a stitch I'm happy with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a strong colour shift, I see a slight colour shift and an equally slight exposure shift.

I think it could be due to the **vignetting removal** of Hugin?

---

(If you really see a strong shift in colour, we have a difference in our displays. When I get home I can try to compare with better displays.)